# Limit selection of checkboxes react

Tags: reactjs, checkbox

What should I do if I would like to limit the selected checkboxes to 3, which you cannot select more than 3 checkboxes. By referring this link https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-silence-b8k2j?file=/src/App.js
How to add some code to limit the selection here?
I am trying to play around this but didn’t figure out

Answer (score 3):

Try this, you need to check length of selected array and checked status of current input

```
const handleOnChange = (position, e) => {
    if (checkedState.filter((i) => i).length >= 3 && e.target.checked) return;
    const updatedCheckedState = checkedState.map((item, index) =>
        index === position ? !item : item
    );

    setCheckedState(updatedCheckedState);

    const totalPrice = updatedCheckedState.reduce((sum, currentState, index) => {
        if (currentState === true) {
            return sum + toppings[index].price;
        }
        return sum;
    }, 0);

    setTotal(totalPrice);
};

<input
    type="checkbox"
    id={`custom-checkbox-${index}`}
    name={name}
    value={name}
    checked={checkedState[index]}
    onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(index, e)}
/>
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-allen-0hik1o?file=/src/App.js:1244-1537)

Answer (score 2):

```
const handleOnChange = (position) => {
    const updatedCheckedState = checkedState.map((item, index) =>
      index === position ? !item : item
    );

    // allow only 3 elements
    if (updatedCheckedState.filter(v => v).length >= 4) {
      return
    }

    setCheckedState(updatedCheckedState);

    const totalPrice = updatedCheckedState.reduce(
      (sum, currentState, index) => {
        if (currentState === true) {
          return sum + toppings[index].price;
        }
        return sum;
      },
      0
    );

    setTotal(totalPrice);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from the state array...

As argument, use a function instead a direct value. It works the same, but it prevents to recreate uselessly an array (then fill it), which will be trashed on every render.

```
  const [checkedState, setCheckedState] = useState(
    () => new Array(toppings.length).fill(false)
  );
```

Then, count how many are currently selected:

```
const selectedCount = checkedState.reduce((sum, currentState, index) => {
    if (currentState === true) {
        return sum + 1;
    }
    return sum;
}, 0);
```

Finally, prevent further selections on the checkboxes which are still selectable:

```
<input
    type="checkbox"
    id={`custom-checkbox-${index}`}
    name={name}
    value={name}
    checked={checkedState[index]}
    onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(index, e)}
    disabled={!checkedState[index] && selectedCount >= 3}
/>
```